# How to make Libreoffice integrate better with KDE graphic environment

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, user-interface, libreoffice

I'm running Libreoffice 4 in Kubuntu 12.04, hence inside a KDE environment.

The graphic isn't at its best, as you can see the menu borders aren't drawn at all, making the interface plain and not very usable and understandable.
[image]

How can I integrate it better with the overall graphic environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to better integrate Libreoffice's interface with KDE, you must remove the `libreoffice-kde` package; it is supposed to provide the required integration, but apparently it doesn't do its job very well.

Then you should install the `libreoffice-gtk` package, you should get the following result:

[image]

I've tried this with Kubuntu, I'm not sure if it works also with other KDE distros but I suppose that is should.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**

*To complete [@Sekhemty's answer](https://superuser.com/a/689295/1671267)*

`libreoffice-gtk` got replaced by `libreoffice-gnome`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add the libreoffice-style-oxygen package, and selected from  System Settings -> Application Appearance -> GTK.

Comment: That package just include an icon set, not an UI integration; and after being installed it's selected from within Libreoffice, not from KDE System Settings.